# Hide and Display Definition List Item using only Data Attribute CSS

Tags: html, css, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to hide and display the definition list content when the mouse was hovered using DATA ATTRIBUTE and CSS only if possible.

What I want to attain is when I hover my mouse on the `<dt>` it will show the `<dd>` content.

Check out my HTML codes:

```
<dl>
    <dt data-name="Open"> About Us</dt>
    <dd>We are the best doctors and nurses. Really we are the best among the rest! We are the best! </dd>
    <dt data-name="Open"> Profile</dt>
    <dd>If you are looking for profile you might be wondering if you don't see any profile here.</dd>
    <dt data-name="Open"> Landmarks</dt>
    <dd>You can check our landmark by checking google maps at Kansas City, Missouri! </dd>
    <dt data-name="Open">Testimonials</dt>
    <dd>This company is great! They have cool stuffs inside! The nurses are cute too! </dd>
    <dt data-name="Open"> Contact Us</dt>
    <dd>You can contact us here: <br/>
        634 Woodhaven Ct
        Clarksville, TN 37042-3918
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
dd {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}

dt {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size : 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    background: #2ebb98;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 14px;

}

dt:first-child { border-top: none; }
dt:nth-last-child(2) { border-bottom: none; }

dt[data="open"]{

}
```

Check out the JSFIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/vphuypj4/

I only want to attain this using ONLY CSS and Data-attribute.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/vphuypj4/1/

Answer (score 4):

You need to hide the `dd`s by default, then use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), along with `:hover` and the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). Note that the attribute value `Open` is case-sensitive.

```
dd {
    display:none;
}

dt[data-name="Open"]:hover + dd{
    display:block;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vphuypj4/2/

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  width: 330px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
  background: #555555;
}
dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
dt {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  background: #2ebb98;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 14px;
}
dt:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
dt:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
dd {
    height:0px;
    padding:0;
    transition: .5s linear;
    overflow:hidden;
}
dt[data-name=Open]:hover + dd {
    height:40px;
    padding:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<dl> <dt data-name="Open"> About Us</dt>

  <dd>We are the best doctors and nurses. Really we are the best among the rest! We are the best!</dd> <dt data-name="Open"> Profile</dt>

  <dd>If you are looking for profile you might be wondering if you don't see any profile here.</dd> <dt data-name="Open"> Landmarks</dt>

  <dd>You can check our landmark by checking google maps at Kansas City, Missouri!</dd> <dt data-name="Open">Testimonials</dt>

  <dd>This company is great! They have cool stuffs inside! The nurses are cute too!</dd> <dt data-name="Open"> Contact Us</dt>

  <dd>You can contact us here:
    <br/>634 Woodhaven Ct Clarksville, TN 37042-3918</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add transition to have a smooth slide?

Answer (score 2):

You could add `@keyframes` for slide down animation on `:hover`.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vphuypj4/4/)**</kbd>

```css
body {
  width: 330px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
  background: #555555;
}
dd {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
dt {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  background: #2ebb98;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 14px;
}
dt:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
dt:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
dt:hover + dd {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: slideDown 0.5s 1;
  animation: slideDown 0.5s 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt data-name="Open"> About Us</dt>
  <dd>We are the best doctors and nurses. Really we are the best among the rest! We are the best!</dd>
  <dt data-name="Open"> Profile</dt>
  <dd>If you are looking for profile you might be wondering if you don't see any profile here.</dd>
  <dt data-name="Open"> Landmarks</dt>
  <dd>You can check our landmark by checking google maps at Kansas City, Missouri!</dd>
  <dt data-name="Open">Testimonials</dt>
  <dd>This company is great! They have cool stuffs inside! The nurses are cute too!</dd>
  <dt data-name="Open"> Contact Us</dt>
  <dd>You can contact us here:
    <br/>634 Woodhaven Ct Clarksville, TN 37042-3918
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Although of course this means setting a fixed height

Comment: @Rhumborl - Well, of course! Since, CSS can't do the math.

Answer (score 2):

For **smooth animation**, dont set the binary `display` property.

Instead, use a `transition` on `max-height`, triggered by the `:hover` state - also transitioning the padding adds a nice effect too.

The reason to use `max-height` instead of `height` is that when using `height` an absolute value needs to be set which all items will always transition to (all items forced to be the same height). Using `max-height`, by setting it to a value greater than the maximum required, items will animate to *only* the height they require (can be different heights)

The benefit over using `keyframes` is the reduced code, and the fact it animates on both `mouseover` and `mouseout`

```css
body {
  width: 330px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
  background: #555555;
}
dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
dt {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  background: #2ebb98;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 14px;
}
dt:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
dt:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
dd {
  max-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
dt[data-name=Open]:hover + dd {
  max-height: 200px; /* <---can be anything, as long as it exceeds the height of the largest item */
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
   <dt data-name="Open"> About Us</dt>
   <dd>We are the best doctors and nurses. Really we are the best among the rest! We are the best!</dd>
   <dt data-name="Open"> Profile</dt>
   <dd>If you are looking for profile you might be wondering if you don't see any profile here.</dd>
   <dt data-name="Open"> Landmarks</dt>
   <dd>You can check our landmark by checking google maps at Kansas City, Missouri!</dd>
   <dt data-name="Open">Testimonials</dt>
   <dd>This company is great! They have cool stuffs inside! The nurses are cute too!</dd>
   <dt data-name="Open"> Contact Us</dt>
   <dd>You can contact us here:
      <br/>634 Woodhaven Ct Clarksville, TN 37042-3918
   </dd>
</dl>
```